# How to get nodes with same name and same attribute name to collection?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've got xml files looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book id="101">3.1256
    <auth-name>Idris Polk</auth-name>
    <auth id="a1">The author is a Professor of Physics at MIT</auth>
    <ph ll="p1">336451234</ph> <ph ll="p2">336051294</ph> <mail>IP.00@yandex.com</mail> <ph ll="p3">336133291</ph>
    </book>
    <book id="105">4.2250
    <auth-name>Andre Olo</auth-name>
    <auth id="a2">The research fellow at NSF</auth>
    <ph ll="p101">336200316</ph>, <ph ll="p102">336151093</ph>, <ph ll="p103">336151094</ph>, <mail>An.olo@yandex.com</mail> <ph ll="p111">336900336</ph>, <ph ll="p112">336154094</ph>, <ph ll="p113">336151098</ph>, <mail>ano_ano@yandex.com</mail>
    </book>
    <ebook id="1">4.2350
    <auth-name>John Bart</auth-name>
    <auth id="ae1">The research fellow at Caltech</auth>
    <ph ll="p50">336200313</ph>, <ph ll="p51">336151090</ph>, <ph ll="p52">336851091</ph>, <ph ll="p53">336151097</ph>, <mail>bart.j@yandex.com</mail> <ph ll="p111">336000311</ph>, <ph ll="p112">336224094</ph>
    </ebook>
...
</books>
```

How do I get the nodes `ph` with attribute `ll` of a particular parent node to a collection when there are more than 2 of the nodes `ph` which are either separated by a whitespace or separated by a comma and a whitespace? If any other character/node(or any type of string) falls between one `ph` node and the next `ph` node then that will not be taken in the collection. e.x. if a `<book id="...">` node contains `ph` nodes in the fashion `<ph ll="1">...</ph> <ph ll="2">...</ph> <mail>...<mail> <ph ll="3">...</ph>` then it won't be added to the collection, however if they are in the order `<ph ll="1">...</ph> <ph ll="2">...</ph> <ph ll="3">...</ph> <mail>...<mail>` then `<ph ll="1">...</ph> <ph ll="2">...</ph> <ph ll="3">...</ph>` should be added as a single element to the collection as there are more than 2 `ph` nodes only separated by a whitespace in a given parent node..

Obviously a simple

```
var cls=doc.Descendants("ph")
                .Where(Attribute("ll"));
```

won't do. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't have commas in xml like that. I wouldn't expect you to even be able to parse that into an `XDocument`.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok..it is just an example...what if there aren't any commas..then?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your requirements, but whitespace is irrelevant to xml. You can have hundreds of spaces or none, xml will parse the same.

Comment: @Crowcoder my requirement is to find nodes `<ph ll="...">` when there are more than 2 of them one after another in a parent node and put them in a collection...

Comment: You would have to parse it as text because no xml parser cares about order of elements either. The sample is poorly formed, xml is meant to be machine readable and hierarchical. I can't help you, this will be a very complex and fragile solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below.  I used xml linq along with a help method. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var books = doc.Descendants("books").Elements().Select(x => new { book = x, sequence = TestChildren(x) }).Where(x => x.sequence != null).ToList();

            string results = string.Join("\n", books.SelectMany(x => x.sequence).Select((x, i) => (i + 1).ToString() + ") " + string.Join("", x.Select(y => y.ToString()))));

            Console.WriteLine(results);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static List<List<XElement>> TestChildren(XElement book)
        {
            List<List<XElement>> results = null;
            List<XElement> children = book.Elements().ToList();
            // get lls, make -1 if not ph
            List<int> lls = children.Select(x => x.Name.LocalName != "ph" ? -1 : int.Parse(((string)x.Attribute("ll")).Substring(1))).ToList();
            //check for 3 in a row incrementing
            int startIndex = -1;
            int numberInSequence = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lls.Count() - 3; i++)
            {
                //test for 3 in a row
                if ((lls[i] + 1 == lls[i + 1]) && (lls[i] + 2 == lls[i + 2]))
                {
                    //if first sequency found set start index and lenght to 3
                    if (startIndex == -1)
                    {
                        startIndex = i;
                        numberInSequence = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //increase length if more than 3
                        numberInSequence++;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //if a sequence has been found add to results
                    if (numberInSequence >= 3)
                    {
                        List<XElement> sequence = new List<XElement>(children.Skip(startIndex).Take(numberInSequence).ToList());
                        if (results == null) results = new List<List<XElement>>();
                        results.Add(sequence);
                        startIndex = -1;
                        numberInSequence = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (numberInSequence >= 3)
            {
                List<XElement> sequence = new List<XElement>(children.Skip(startIndex).Take(numberInSequence).ToList());
                if (results == null) results = new List<List<XElement>>();
                results.Add(sequence);
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the 3 or more `<ph l=".."l>` nodes as the output..the above xml should give the output as i.e. elements of the collection `books` should be

1)`<ph ll="p101">336200316</ph>, <ph ll="p102">336151093</ph>, <ph ll="p103">336151094</ph>`
2)
`<ph ll="p111">336900336</ph>, <ph ll="p112">336154094</ph>, <ph ll="p113">336151098</ph>`
3)
`<ph ll="p50">336200313</ph>, <ph ll="p51">336151090</ph>, <ph ll="p52">336851091</ph>, <ph ll="p53">336151097</ph>`

Comment: Updated code again to get more than one sequence from each book.

Comment: How do I extract the matched consecutive `<ph>` nodes from the collections book?