# Need help finding specific nodes in a incremented sequence?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've got an array of strings in the below fashion(each element contains at least 3 nodes by name `xref` with attributes `ref-type` and `rid`)

```
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref20">[20]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref21">[21]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref22">[22]</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>
```

I'm trying to go through each element of the array and find 3 or more nodes `xref` that have their respective `rid` attribute value incremented by +1 excluding the text `rid` and output them to a console or a file.

I've done

```
foreach (var element in xrefs)
{
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse("<root>"+element+"</root>",LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

    int len = xd.Descendants("xref").Count();

    var values = from El in xd.Descendants("xref").Take(len - 2)
        where El.CompareNext() && El.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault().CompareNext()
        select El;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-',50)+"\r\n"+element+"\r\n");
    }
}
```

where `xrefs` is the array and `ElementsAfterSelf()` is a method created as follows

```
static class T1
{

    public static Boolean CompareNext(this XElement xe)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(xe.Attribute("rid").Value.Replace("ref", "")) + 1 == Convert.ToInt16(xe.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault().Attribute("rid").Value.Replace("ref", ""));
    }
}
```

Now the result it produces is like

```
--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref20">[20]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref21">[21]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref22">[22]</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>


--------------------------------------------------
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>
```

It is writing the below strings two times but I only want it once since it is the same thing

```
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>
```

Can anyone help?

Here is a [sample xml file](https://codeshare.io/5XlLzY) and the [full code](https://codeshare.io/5z3lQW) I'm using

I'm trying to find some consecutive nodes `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref...">...</xref>` (when there are **3** or more) in some xml files that are separated by either **a comma** or **a comma and a space** and write them to a log file. The consecutive nodes that I'm trying to identify should have their respective attribute `rid` values incremented by +1 minus the text `ref`. Any other `xref` nodes with different `rid` values apart from `refX` are not required to check.

Comment: How did `ref106` get in there? What is "the text rid"? `ElementsAfterSelf` or `CompareNext`?

Comment: What "them" do you want to output? Why are you doing `foreach (value` and not using `value` in the body?

Comment: @NetMage `CompareNext` not `ElementsAfterSelf` my bad ...btw check the updated question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a LINQ version could significantly improve the code or understanding.

Since you want to output the text between the elements, you can write a helper function to output the `XNode`s between two nodes:

```
var dashes = new String('-', 50);

void WriteNodesBetween(XNode from, XNode to) {
    Console.WriteLine(dashes);
    var xn = from;
    for (; xn != to; xn = xn.NextNode)
        Console.Write(xn.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(xn.ToString());
}
```

Then you can convert your strings to `XNode`s and scan through the elements gathering the sequentially numbered elements. Once you have them gathered, you can output all the elements and the nodes between if at least three sequential elements were found.

```
foreach (var element in xrefs) {
    var xd = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + element + "</root>").Descendants("xref");

    var outElements = new List<XElement>() { xd.First() };
    foreach (var el in xd.Skip(1)) {
        if (!outElements.Last().ISSequential(el)) {
            if (outElements.Count >= 3)
                WriteNodesBetween(outElements.First(), outElements.Last());
            outElements.Clear();
        }
        outElements.Add(el);
    }
    if (outElements.Count >= 3)
        WriteNodesBetween(outElements.First(), outElements.Last());
}
```

This uses another helper to test if two elements are sequential.

```
public static class Ext {
    public static bool ISSequential(this XElement xe, XElement nextxe) => Convert.ToInt16(xe.Attribute("rid").Value.Replace("ref", "")) + 1 == Convert.ToInt16(nextxe.Attribute("rid").Value.Replace("ref", ""));
}
```

Comment: your code still produces the duplicate values as mine...i.e. `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>` and `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>` is still written to the output twice...that should not happen...

Comment: also if possible, only the consecutive elements with +1 incremented `rid` should be displayed i.e. for `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>` the output should display `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref>`

Comment: as `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>` has the `rid` value as **ref106** and not **ref105** as it should be for a incremented value

Comment: My output shows each string only once. Also, your program outputs `element`, which is the entire original string, which e.g. would include **ref106**. What would you expect output from ref101,ref102,ref103,ref106,ref107,ref108?

Comment: `ref101,ref102,ref103` and `ref106,ref107,ref108` as two separate strings

Comment: Also for ref9,ref101,ref102,ref103,ref106,ref107,ref108,ref109, ref113 it would give two different strings `ref101,ref102,ref103` and `ref106,ref107,ref108,ref109`

Comment: Rewrote my answer to output just sequential elements and nodes between, I assumed you didn't need nodes after the last element.

Comment: This code is getting to be like my code in previous posting the Don doesn't like but works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095329/how-to-get-nodes-with-same-name-and-same-attribute-name-to-collection/49095693#49095693

Comment: @NetMage can you explain the line `for (; xn != to; xn = xn.NextNode)` in your code, why does the for loop start with a semicolon? I've never used anything like it befor...

Comment: The empty initial part of the `for` is because I need access to the iteration variable `xn` outside the `for` loop, so I initialize it before the loop, and I don't need any other variable inside the loop so that part can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I put this as a separate answer as I am not sure I think it is better or clearer, but it is possible to use LINQ to find the sequences by grouping them.

I created a variation of my `Scan` extension, which is an implementation of the APL scan operator, similar to `Aggregate` but it returns the intermediate results as a sequence.

The `ScanPair` extension uses a `ValueTuple` to match the intermediate results with the current element in the result sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combine) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return prevkv;
                prevkv = (combine(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
            }
            yield return prevkv;
        }
    }
}
```

Using `ScanPair`, you can create an extension to group on a predicate:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupByWhile<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> test, Func<T, TRes> result) =>
    src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => test(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key+1)
       .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => result(kvp.Value));
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> test) => src.GroupByWhile(test, e => e);
```

Using `GroupByWhile` you can create an extension to group by sequential values:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupBySequential<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, int> SeqNum, Func<T, TRes> result) => src.GroupByWhile((prev,cur) => SeqNum(prev)+1 == SeqNum(cur), result);
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupBySequential<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, int> SeqNum) => src.GroupBySequential(SeqNum, e => e);
```

Now with `GroupBySequential` available, you can pull out the sequences from each string:

```
var dashes = new String('-', 50);

void WriteNodesBetween(XNode from, XNode to) {
    Console.WriteLine(dashes);
    var xn = from;
    for (; xn != to; xn = xn.NextNode)
        Console.Write(xn.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(xn.ToString());
}

foreach (var element in xrefs) {
    var xd = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + element + "</root>").Descendants("xref");
    var refseqs = xd.GroupBySequential(xref => xref.RefValue().Value);
    foreach (var seq in refseqs.Where(sg => sg.Count() >= 3))
        WriteNodesBetween(seq.First(), seq.Last());
}
```

Comment: it looks more complicated...but thanks for showing this alternative method...btw your previous answer(that I marked as answer) has a minor issue that I noticed recently, if the file contains nodes like `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref20">[20]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref21">[21]</xref> <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref22">[22]</xref>` the output shows it as `<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref20">[20]</xref><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref21">[21]</xref><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref22">[22]</xref>` i.e. without the spaces in between but I wanted it as it is in the file exactly..

Comment: Unfortunately the point of `XDocument`, etc is to abstract away things like spacing. This sounds like you need to take a different approach all together. What is your real issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score -2):

Your xml is an array of elements so I do not understand what you are trying to do.

```
<Root>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref20">[20]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref21">[21]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref22">[22]</xref>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref2">[2]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref3">[3]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref101">101</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref102">102</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref103">103</xref>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref104">104</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref106">106</xref>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref4">[4]</xref>
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref11">[11]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref12">[12]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</xref> 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref14">[14]</xref>
</Root>
```

Comment: Did you mean "any" == "an"?

Comment: What is the difference between this solutions and my answer to your previous question at following posting? My TestChildren() method can easily be modified to handle both cases. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095329/how-to-get-nodes-with-same-name-and-same-attribute-name-to-collection/49095693#49095693

Comment: @jdweng Its a bit too long of a process for my liking, I was hoping for a simple one line linq condition added in the `values` varible or something like that checks for the next `xref` and what strings are in between and also get 3 or more of `xref` in the variable `values` itself, something short but gets the job done

Comment: My code uses simple linq.  The helper method is complicated but who cares.  It gets the job done.  Why create a one line linq that nobody can understand and nobody can modify.  In the 60s they use to call this power programming.  Try to reduce the size of the source code which used very expensive memory.  When memory became cheap it was more important to write code that could be maintained.  Employees change jobs often and new employees were needed to modify existing code.  So the code needed to be well documented and easy to change.